# Simple lower bound for a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ in $\mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}$ such that $\det(A) > 0$? Is there a simple lower bound for $\det(A)$ in terms of the entries of $A$?

**Edit:** *Motivation*: Let $M$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. I want to compute a lower bound for 
$$
\frac{\det(A^*_i)}{\det(A_i)},  
$$
where $\det(A_i)$ is a $n \times n$ matrix consisting of columns of $M$ and $A^*_i$ equals $A_i$ where the $i$-th column is replaced by some column vector $b$ (Cramer's Rule). I know that $\det(A_i)$ can be upper bounded by $2 \langle M \rangle$, where $\langle M \rangle$ denotes the encoding length of $M$. The encoding size of the lower bound should be bounded polynomially in $n$ and the encoding size of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "sort of". If the entries of $A$ are all integers, then $\det A$ is an integer, so if $\det A>0$ we must have $\det A\ge 1$. This can be generalised to if the entries of $A$ are all rational - multiply $A$ by a positive integer $k$ such that each entry of $kA$ is an integer. It is not hard to see then that $\det A\ge\frac1{k^n}$. If $A$ has arbitrary real or complex entries then of course $A$ can have arbitrarily small determinant.

Comment: Thanks, I shoud have added that the encoding size of the lower bound should be bounded polynomially in $n$ and the encoding size of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

i) If you consider the determinant as a function of the matrix, what exactly you mean by "in terms of the entries of $A$", the determinant is fully specified by the entries in the matrix, so you have more then just a lower bound, you have the exact value if you know the entries... or what you have in mind? For example if $n = 2$ the formula is
$$
 \det\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} = a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12}a_{21}
$$
so maybe you could write $\det(\ldots) \ge \min\{a_{11}, a_{22}\}^2 - \max\{a_{12}, a_{21}\}^2$, does this help you?

ii) If you consider the determinant more a property of the linear transformation associated with the matrix, then it should be the same regardless in what base you express your matrix, so your lower bound should in some sense maybe express this invariant too, do you want to change it if you change the basis?

iii) As the determinant equals the product of the eigenvalues, this could be used to derive some lower bounds maybe, for example if $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of your matrix, then
$$
 \min_{i=1,\ldots,n} \lambda_i^n \le \det(A) \le n \max_{i=1,\ldots,n}  \lambda_i^n.
$$

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. I have large number of matrices, so I want to quickly compute a lower bound. Please, see my edit.

Comment: Maybe you should say if your matrices have a special form, for example are they sparse? And are their entries bounded? Then it would be possible to derive better bounds for their determinants.

Comment: No, I want to compute a lower bound for $|det(A)|/U$ where $U$ is some upper bound. The matrix $A$ consists of columns of an $m\times n$ matrix $M$. So I want to find a lower bound for $|\det(A)|$ over all such $n \times n$ matrices $A$.

Comment: If you consider arbitrary matrices with $\det(A) > 0$, then the only lower bound is $0$ itself, because for arbitrary small $0 < \varepsilon$ we have $$ \begin{pmatrix} \varepsilon & 0 \\ 0 & \varepsilon \end{pmatrix} = \varepsilon^2 \to 0 \mbox{ as } \varepsilon \to 0. $$

Comment: Thanks! Let's say my matrix $M$ is fixed, i.e., we know all the numbers. Does this change anything?

Comment: Guess you want to avoid the computation of the determinant itself (any bound on computational resources?), maybe you could try to approximate the smallest eigenvalue, and then use what I have written above to get a lower bound, for eigenvalue approximation see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration

Comment: Please see my edit. I provided some background information.